# Magento 2 : How to check SQL INJECTION VULNERABILITY for all my Magento 2 modules?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, sql

In my current project we have installed lot third party extensions and created lot of custom extensions.

How to check SQL INJECTION VULNERABILITY in my all module.

Comment: Any tool or query available for check SQL INJECTION VULNERABILITY